# How to retrieve response headers after a failed jquery-ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling, http-headers

The question apparently is simple. I just want to recover the headers produced by a failed POST request, using jquery.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 'wrong_token_to_force_fail');
        },
        data: "form_data",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

        success: function (response) {
            var message = "File correctly uploaded.";
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
    });
```

Despite I'm able to see the status code, and even an error message inside Chrome's Developers Tools, I'm not able to receive that information inside my jquery error callback.

[image: error message in web browser]

I've looked for similar questions, but none of them have solved my issue. The most suggested solution is to use the getAllResponseHeaders and getResponseHeader methods, but in my case they are returning an empty string.

**EDIT**

This is the output of "console.log(jqXHR);"

[image: Output jqXHR]

Comment: If `getResponseHeader` returns you empty string, there is no other way to do that. Are you sure, that you write header name without any typos ?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I've written the header name without typos. jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Type') returns me an empty string and also jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders()

Comment: Maybe your question is missing the word error/failed in order to be understood properly...

Comment: Title edited, thank you @LuisKabongo